# Using for setup.cfg to declare dependencies for github's dependabot

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, dependabot

in this tutorial for [python packaging tutorarial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) it is recommended to use setup.cfg over setup.py to declare dependencies. However on github under "Dependency graph", it is written that only dependencies declared under setup.py or pyproject.toml are read. Does that mean that it is not recommended to declare the dependencies in setup.cfg?

Or if it is recommended how can I tell dependabot to check for dependencies under setup.cfg?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is yet not supported, see the discussion on [Github](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/2133) where the issue is still open (the project is open source and waiting for devs to contribute - the project is in Ruby)

Comment: BTW it is possible (and acceptable) to put both `setup.cfg` and 'requirements.txt, since they have different purposes. The only headache is to keep them in sync